# How do make this stack cards effect without position:sticky css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do i ignore position:sticky properties and make this same effect without position sticky? Because lots of browser does nto support this sticky position. You will see there is stack-cards__item class name has a css that called position:sticky.. is there any way where i can ignore this css and keep this same stacking cards effect..

```
<script>document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].className += " js";</script>
<style>
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto; }
.col {
  max-width: 100%; }
.is-visible {
  display: block !important; }
.is-hidden {
  display: none !important; }
.stack-cards {
  --stack-cards-gap: 10; }
.stack-cards__item {
  position: relative;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 10;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
          transform-origin: center top;
  overflow: hidden; }
 
  .stack-cards__item > * {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; }
  </style>
  <div class="container max-width-adaptive-md margin-bottom-lg">
      <ul class="stack-cards js-stack-cards">
        <li data-theme="default" class="stack-cards__item bg radius-lg shadow-md js-stack-cards__item">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="col-6 flex items-center height-100%">
              <div class="text-component padding-md ">
                <h2>Card One</h2>
                <p class="display@xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <p><a href="#0" class="btn btn--accent">Read more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 height-100%">
              <img class="block width-100% height-100% object-cover" src="assets/img/img-1.jpg" alt="Image description">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      
        <li data-theme="default" class="stack-cards__item bg radius-lg shadow-md js-stack-cards__item">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="col-6 flex items-center height-100%">
              <div class="text-component padding-md ">
                <h2>Card Two</h2>
                <p class="display@xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <p><a href="#0" class="btn btn--accent">Read more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 height-100%">
              <img class="block width-100% height-100% object-cover" src="assets/img/img-2.jpg" alt="Image description">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li data-theme="default" class="stack-cards__item bg radius-lg shadow-md js-stack-cards__item">
          <div class="grid">
            <div class="col-6 flex items-center height-100%">
              <div class="text-component padding-md ">
                <h2>Card Three</h2>
                <p class="display@xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                <p><a href="#0" class="btn btn--accent">Read more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6 height-100%">
              <img class="block width-100% height-100% object-cover" src="assets/img/img-3.jpg" alt="Image description">
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  
    <div class="container max-width-adaptive-sm">
      <div class="text-component line-height-lg v-space-md">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem repellat non ratione eum provident quaerat obcaecati dicta autem voluptates sit cum quis distinctio, atque sint commodi reprehenderit perspiciatis iure velit molestiae eos molestias ipsa nihil quia? Porro tempore in fugit, aspernatur et temporibus aliquam magnam adipisci deleniti dicta repellat alias nostrum impedit quidem odit excepturi nam. Itaque numquam unde quae dignissimos exercitationem placeat, ipsa amet tempora vitae ullam animi! Hic asperiores in esse atque expedita dolorem officia illo commodi fugit earum ab, assumenda optio, sed repellat. Maiores laudantium reprehenderit suscipit accusamus assumenda, debitis nemo ut sapiente numquam doloremque alias explicabo minus autem harum illum dicta. Unde obcaecati inventore repellat id eligendi eaque, rerum aliquam maiores aspernatur cumque tenetur quo qui mollitia atque quasi voluptate ipsum neque explicabo voluptatem quibusdam beatae quae iste vero doloribus! Natus libero quibusdam molestias harum atque, assumenda doloribus quis, quam corporis, voluptas suscipit magni! Enim sapiente totam consequatur repellat maxime placeat perferendis iste maiores soluta, obcaecati incidunt expedita eius cumque ipsa quo sed. Minus distinctio culpa cumque labore nulla laborum ex, explicabo magni mollitia eaque aliquam vero blanditiis quae, id necessitatibus error voluptas harum tempora sint porro. Facilis beatae quasi soluta et ipsum suscipit repellendus inventore.</p>
  
        <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, ipsam molestias. Fuga similique, dolor tempora rerum perferendis ipsam ullam doloribus beatae esse facilis quae sit excepturi expedita non, sunt accusantium magnam? Animi nesciunt nostrum eligendi iusto voluptatum hic qui. Quod distinctio qui nobis et doloremque. Fuga, itaque? Laborum dignissimos nobis quaerat optio voluptatum similique unde, neque cupiditate, vel, fugiat dolore? Accusantium neque deserunt ducimus enim, illum laborum magni ipsam eos optio aspernatur nam necessitatibus quod natus, dolor laboriosam illo velit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
<script>
  (function() {
  var StackCards = function(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.items = this.element.getElementsByClassName('js-stack-cards__item');
    this.scrollingFn = false;
    this.scrolling = false;
    initStackCardsEffect(this); 
    initStackCardsResize(this); 
  };

  function initStackCardsEffect(element) { // use Intersection Observer to trigger animation
    setStackCards(element); // store cards CSS properties
        var observer = new IntersectionObserver(stackCardsCallback.bind(element), { threshold: [0, 1] });
        observer.observe(element.element);
  };

  function initStackCardsResize(element) { // detect resize to reset gallery
    element.element.addEventListener('resize-stack-cards', function(){
      setStackCards(element);
      animateStackCards.bind(element);
    });
  };
  
  function stackCardsCallback(entries) { // Intersection Observer callback
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting) {
      if(this.scrollingFn) return; // listener for scroll event already added
      stackCardsInitEvent(this);
    } else {
      if(!this.scrollingFn) return; // listener for scroll event already removed
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scrollingFn);
      this.scrollingFn = false;
    }
  };
  
  function stackCardsInitEvent(element) {
    element.scrollingFn = stackCardsScrolling.bind(element);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', element.scrollingFn);
  };

  function stackCardsScrolling() {
    if(this.scrolling) return;
    this.scrolling = true;
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animateStackCards.bind(this));
  };

  function setStackCards(element) {
    // store wrapper properties
    element.marginY = getComputedStyle(element.element).getPropertyValue('--stack-cards-gap');
    getIntegerFromProperty(element); // convert element.marginY to integer (px value)
    element.elementHeight = element.element.offsetHeight;

    // store card properties
    var cardStyle = getComputedStyle(element.items[0]);
    element.cardTop = Math.floor(parseFloat(cardStyle.getPropertyValue('top')));
    element.cardHeight = Math.floor(parseFloat(cardStyle.getPropertyValue('height')));

    // store window property
    element.windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    // reset margin + translate values
    if(isNaN(element.marginY)) {
      element.element.style.paddingBottom = '0px';
    } else {
      element.element.style.paddingBottom = (element.marginY*(element.items.length - 1))+'px';
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < element.items.length; i++) {
      if(isNaN(element.marginY)) {
        element.items[i].style.transform = 'none;';
      } else {
        element.items[i].style.transform = 'translateY('+element.marginY*i+'px)';
      }
    }
  };

  function getIntegerFromProperty(element) {
    var node = document.createElement('div');
    node.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:0; visbility: hidden;position: absolute; height:'+element.marginY);
    element.element.appendChild(node);
    element.marginY = parseInt(getComputedStyle(node).getPropertyValue('height'));
    element.element.removeChild(node);
  };

  function animateStackCards() {
    if(isNaN(this.marginY)) { // --stack-cards-gap not defined - do not trigger the effect
      this.scrolling = false;
      return; 
    }

    var top = this.element.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    if( this.cardTop - top + this.element.windowHeight - this.elementHeight - this.cardHeight + this.marginY + this.marginY*this.items.length > 0) { 
      this.scrolling = false;
      return;
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) { // use only scale
      var scrolling = this.cardTop - top - i*(this.cardHeight+this.marginY);
      if(scrolling > 0) {  
        var scaling = i == this.items.length - 1 ? 1 : (this.cardHeight - scrolling*0.05)/this.cardHeight;
        this.items[i].style.transform = 'translateY('+this.marginY*i+'px) scale('+scaling+')';
      } else {
        this.items[i].style.transform = 'translateY('+this.marginY*i+'px)';
      }
    }

    this.scrolling = false;
  };

  // initialize StackCards object
  var stackCards = document.getElementsByClassName('js-stack-cards'),
    intersectionObserverSupported = ('IntersectionObserver' in window && 'IntersectionObserverEntry' in window && 'intersectionRatio' in window.IntersectionObserverEntry.prototype),
    reducedMotion = Util.osHasReducedMotion();
    
    if(stackCards.length > 0 && intersectionObserverSupported && !reducedMotion) { 
    var stackCardsArray = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < stackCards.length; i++) {
            (function(i){
        stackCardsArray.push(new StackCards(stackCards[i]));
      })(i);
    }
    
    var resizingId = false,
      customEvent = new CustomEvent('resize-stack-cards');
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      clearTimeout(resizingId);
      resizingId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
    });

    function doneResizing() {
      for( var i = 0; i < stackCardsArray.length; i++) {
        (function(i){stackCardsArray[i].element.dispatchEvent(customEvent)})(i);
      };
    };
    }
}());
</script>
```

Comment: Please put your code in a snippet to help people resolving your issue

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you using bootstrap on this one? If yes, which version?

Comment: actually a lot of browsers do support position: sticky. 
https://caniuse.com/css-sticky

Comment: `reducedMotion = Util.osHasReducedMotion()` => `Util is not defined`

Comment: no not using any kind of framework..

Comment: @CharlesLavalard if u run this code in a normal html file this box is working fine. no issue but on any snippet this is not working... DOnt know why

Comment: hi @julien.giband this is working fine as a normal html file on local computer. But not working in any snippet...

Comment: @Aminulhasan nope. Still getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Util is not defined` at line 205 if I copy all this to an HTML file. And that's to be expected, since there is no declaration of `Util` anywhere, nor is there any reference to an external js file that would declare it.

Comment: @julien.giband any solution? for that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, still a little problem with what comes after the cards: it appears below the sticky cards. You can fix that fiddling with `z-index`.

The principle is that any time a card comes to the top of the viewport, we clone it, position the clone as `fixed`, and make the original card invisible.

*Better viewed in full page mode:*

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.stack-cards__item');
cards.forEach(card => card.style.zIndex = 1);
const offsetTop = cards[0].getBoundingClientRect().y - document.body.getBoundingClientRect().y;
window.addEventListener('scroll', _e => {
  cards.forEach((card, index) => {
    const pos = card.getBoundingClientRect();
    const STICK_AT = 10;
    if (pos.y < offsetTop) {
      //console.log(pos.y, pos.height);
      if (!card.stickyClone) {
        card.stickyClone = card.cloneNode(true);
        card.stickyClone.style.position = 'fixed';
        card.stickyClone.style.width = '100%';
        card.stickyClone.style.zIndex = 0;
        card.stickyClone.style.top = offsetTop + 'px';
        card.parentNode.append(card.stickyClone);
        card.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }
    } else if (card.stickyClone) {
      card.style.visibility = '';
      card.stickyClone.remove();
      card.stickyClone = null;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: white; /* added that for tests */
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.col {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.is-visible {
  display: block !important;
}

.is-hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

.stack-cards {
  --stack-cards-gap: 10;
}

.stack-cards__item {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
  transform-origin: center top;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stack-cards__item > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container max-width-adaptive-md margin-bottom-lg">
  <ul class="stack-cards js-stack-cards">
    <li data-theme="default" class="stack-cards__item bg radius-lg shadow-md js-stack-cards__item">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-6 flex items-center height-100%">
          <div class="text-component padding-md ">
            <h2>Card One</h2>
            <p class="display@xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <p><a href="#0" class="btn btn--accent">Read more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 height-100%">
          <img class="block width-100% height-100% object-cover" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/card1/200/300" alt="Image description">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li data-theme="default" class="stack-cards__item bg radius-lg shadow-md js-stack-cards__item">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-6 flex items-center height-100%">
          <div class="text-component padding-md ">
            <h2>Card Two</h2>
            <p class="display@xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <p><a href="#0" class="btn btn--accent">Read more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 height-100%">
          <img class="block width-100% height-100% object-cover" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/card2/200/300" alt="Image description">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li data-theme="default" class="stack-cards__item bg radius-lg shadow-md js-stack-cards__item">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="col-6 flex items-center height-100%">
          <div class="text-component padding-md ">
            <h2>Card Three</h2>
            <p class="display@xs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <p><a href="#0" class="btn btn--accent">Read more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 height-100%">
          <img class="block width-100% height-100% object-cover" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/card3/200/300" alt="Image description">
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="container max-width-adaptive-sm">
  <div class="text-component line-height-lg v-space-md">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Rem repellat non ratione eum provident quaerat obcaecati dicta autem voluptates sit cum quis distinctio, atque sint commodi reprehenderit perspiciatis iure velit molestiae eos molestias ipsa
      nihil quia? Porro tempore in fugit, aspernatur et temporibus aliquam magnam adipisci deleniti dicta repellat alias nostrum impedit quidem odit excepturi nam. Itaque numquam unde quae dignissimos exercitationem placeat, ipsa amet tempora vitae ullam
      animi! Hic asperiores in esse atque expedita dolorem officia illo commodi fugit earum ab, assumenda optio, sed repellat. Maiores laudantium reprehenderit suscipit accusamus assumenda, debitis nemo ut sapiente numquam doloremque alias explicabo minus
      autem harum illum dicta. Unde obcaecati inventore repellat id eligendi eaque, rerum aliquam maiores aspernatur cumque tenetur quo qui mollitia atque quasi voluptate ipsum neque explicabo voluptatem quibusdam beatae quae iste vero doloribus! Natus
      libero quibusdam molestias harum atque, assumenda doloribus quis, quam corporis, voluptas suscipit magni! Enim sapiente totam consequatur repellat maxime placeat perferendis iste maiores soluta, obcaecati incidunt expedita eius cumque ipsa quo sed.
      Minus distinctio culpa cumque labore nulla laborum ex, explicabo magni mollitia eaque aliquam vero blanditiis quae, id necessitatibus error voluptas harum tempora sint porro. Facilis beatae quasi soluta et ipsum suscipit repellendus inventore.</p>

    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus, ipsam molestias. Fuga similique, dolor tempora rerum perferendis ipsam ullam doloribus beatae esse facilis quae sit excepturi expedita non, sunt accusantium magnam? Animi nesciunt
      nostrum eligendi iusto voluptatum hic qui. Quod distinctio qui nobis et doloremque. Fuga, itaque? Laborum dignissimos nobis quaerat optio voluptatum similique unde, neque cupiditate, vel, fugiat dolore? Accusantium neque deserunt ducimus enim, illum
      laborum magni ipsam eos optio aspernatur nam necessitatibus quod natus, dolor laboriosam illo velit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: only problem with this one is after last one apear that should scroll to top like normal. I mean after last one come to veiwport position should be changed as realtive